# O background-image não está cobrindo toda a página no celular

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Fiz um código de html5 e css3 onde eu teria que colocar uma imagem sobre a outra de forma que a imagem que ficasse sobreposta estaria centralizada, até essa parte consegui fazer, mas quando vou abrir a página no celular fica uma linha branca no final da página, já tentei colocar o tamanho do body e do html em 100% e não funcionou. Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Ah, outra coisa, se possível não mande a solução usando media queries ou flexbox, ainda não aprendi essas técnicas. Segue o codigo:

*página do html*

```
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Desafio011</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div id="img01">
            <img src="imagens/astronauta.png" alt="Imagem de um astronauta">
        </div>
</body>
</html>

*página do Css*


*{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}/*Reset*/

html, body {
    height: 100vh
}
body{
    background-image: url(imagens/espaco.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 93vh;
    background-position: center center;
   
}
#img01{
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score -2):

Infelizmente o problema está relacionado a unidade **vh** e não vi nenhum plano de correção para este problema, sugiro que use percentual combinado de outras propriedades css para não sofrer com esse problema.